# Re-arranging products of exponentials for a Lie algebra

Tags: operator-theory, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Suppose I have $n$ operators $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, which are closed under commutators:
$$[X_i,X_j]=c_1X_1+\cdots+c_nX_n,$$
where $c_j$ are constants (which will depend on $i$ and $j$).

Now consider a product of exponentials:
$$\xi=\exp(\alpha_1X_1)\cdots\exp(\alpha_nX_n).$$
"Most of the time" I should also be able to write this a product of the same operators in a different order:
$$\xi=\exp(\beta_1X_{\sigma(1)})\cdots\exp(\beta_nX_{\sigma(n)}),$$
where $\sigma$ is some permutation. My questions are:

1. If it is possible to write $\xi$ as two different arrangements, is there a way to find the $\beta_i$ given $\sigma$, $\alpha_i$, and the algebra commutation relations?
2. When can this fail? Is it possible that $\xi$ could be expressed as one ordering, but not another?

This question comes from considering the Wei-Norman expansion for matrix differential equations. These will have singularities at some points, but I wonder how much flexibility I have to jump between coordinate systems as I approach the singularities.

Comment: Title: what do you mean by a *closed* Lie algebra? This is a vector space.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that there is a finite set of operators such that when you take the commutators of any two, the result is a linear combination of the others. I come from a quantum mechanics background where we often have infinite dimensional vector spaces, where the Lie algebras don't close.

Comment: We also have infinite dimensional Lie algebras in mathematics. If a space of operators isn't closed under commutator, it is simply not called a Lie algebra. This can happen in finite or infinite dimension.

Comment: Maybe work directly with the Lie group to check your results?

Comment: @DietrichBurde oh yes of course. By "close" I was meaning "is finite", but you're right that isn't correct terminology.

Comment: @JulesBesson Thanks, I think I could figure out the transformations for small specific algebras. But I'm wondering if there are known results for a general Lie algebra. It seems like the re-arrangement must be determined by the commutator table.